# How can I cope/create/circumenvent a rule in Yacc/Bison that handles multiple %types?

Tags: c, bison, yacc

I'm trying to create a LALR(1) parser in Yacc/Bison that can accept commands with flexible grammar.  An example is controlling the environment in a house by adjusting room temperatures (floats), window positions (ints), and ceiling fans (enum).  Example (desired) grammar would be:

```
set kitchen 22.5, den 0 24.0, bathroom fast 25, kitchen slow
```

I'm stuck on how to handle the stacked data for what I've called a "room_arg" in the rules.  I could add a `room_arg arg` type to the `%union` statement, set `%type <arg> room_arg` and make the "room_arg" rule:

```
room_arg:  TOK_CIELING_FAN { $$.fan = $1; }
         | TOK_WINDOW      { $$.window_position = $1; }
         | TOK_THERMOSTAT  { $$.temperature = $1; }
```

But when it comes to doing reduction of the "room_arg" rule to "room_args" - I've got to figure out which stack items are which.  Add to that that the "room_cmd" for a particular room ("kitchen" in the example) doesn't require grouping in the command adds to my challenge.

Changing the format of the command would be lovely, but, alas not possible.

**Could someone suggest a strategy for implementation, or perhaps improvement to the parser logic to make things simpler?**

The grammar to criticize is below.

```
%{
typedef enum fan_setting_tag { OFF, SLOW, MEDIUM, FAST } fan_setting;

struct room_arg_tag {
   int          window_position;
   fan_setting  fan;
   float    temperature;
   char *   room_name;
} room_arg;
%}
%token TOK_ROOM
%token TOK_CIELING_FAN
%token TOK_WINDOW
%token TOK_THERMOSTAT
%token TOK_SET

%type <fan>     TOK_CIELING_FAN
%type <window>  TOK_WINDOW
%type <tempr>   TOK_THERMOSTAT
%type <str>     TOK_ROOM

%union {
    int         window;
    float       tempr;
    fan_setting fan;
}

%%

command: /* empty */ | cmd command

cmd: TOK_SET room_cmds { execute_command( ... ); }

room_cmds: room_cmd
         | room_cmd ',' room_cmds

room_cmd:  TOK_ROOM room_args

room_args: room_arg
         | room_arg room_args

room_arg:  TOK_CIELING_FAN
         | TOK_WINDOW
         | TOK_THERMOSTAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where you really want inherited attributes.  You can simulate them with extra actions, but unfortunately yacc and bison don't give you a way to do them more directly ([btyacc](http://www.siber.com/btyacc/) provides syntacic sugar to make this much easier.)

Basically what you do is use embedded actions to setup the inherited attributes and use `$0` to access them within the lower level rules.

With btyacc you would do:

```
%union {
    int         window;
    float       tempr;
    fan_setting fan;
    room_arg    *room;
}

%token<fan>     TOK_CIELING_FAN
%token<window>  TOK_WINDOW
%token<tempr>   TOK_THERMOSTAT
%token<str>     TOK_ROOM

%type<room> room_cmds(<room>)
%type<>     room_cmd(<room>), room_args(<room>), room_arg(<room>)

%%

command: /* empty */ | cmd command ;

cmd: TOK_SET room_cmds(new_room_arg()) { execute_command( ... ); } ;

room_cmds($room):
           room_cmd($room) { $$ = $room; }
         | room_cmd($room) ',' room_cmds($room) { $$ = $room; }
;

room_cmd($room):  TOK_ROOM room_args($room) { $room->room_name = $1; } ;

room_args($room): 
           room_arg($room)
         | room_arg($room) room_args($room)
;

room_arg($room):
           TOK_CIELING_FAN { $room->fan = $1; }
         | TOK_WINDOW      { $room->window_position = $1; }
         | TOK_THERMOSTAT  { $room->temperature = $1; }
;
```

In yacc or bison, this becomes something like:

```
cmd: TOK_SET { $$ = new_room_arg(); } room_cmds { execute_command(...)' } '
room_cmds:
      room_cmd { $$ = $<room>0; }
    | room_cmd ',' { $$ = $<room>0; } room_cmds { $$ = $<room>0; }
;
room_cmd: TOK_ROOM { $$ = $<room>0; } room_args { $<room>0->room_name = $1; }
```

and so forth, which is tricky to get right (get all the right types in the right places) and somewhat error prone.

In this specific case, you could just use a global variable (as there's no recursion involved), but that doesn't work too well in more complex cases.